# Sometimes some micro front end is not loaded properly in single spa framework

Tags: angular, systemjs, micro-frontend, single-spa

In my main index.html file, I had given following kind of routes.

```
<template id="single-spa-layout">
<single-spa-router>
    <div class="main-content">
        <route path="login">
          <application name="login"></application>
        </route>
        <route path="main">
          <application name="banner"></application>
          <application name="footerApp"></application>
        </route>
    </div>
</single-spa-router>
```

When route 'main' is loaded it sometimes rendered only one microfront end either banner or footerApp.
Any solution for it ?

Comment: Anything useful in the console that you can share? Also check whether or not the application element is there in the html, but it's not rendering its contents. If that's the case, then the problem might be with application component

Comment: application is not a component, it is used for routing purpose used in single spa.
You can refer this. https://github.com/joeldenning/coexisting-angular-microfrontends/blob/master/root-html-file/index.html

Comment: Ok, so by the looks of it I don't think it was designed to load simultaneously 2+ apps on the same route, which would make sense because how would 2 different apps behave if loaded together? what about their internal routing? From what I see you want to play with these app as if they were components. You could also try to write a post here 
https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues
maybe they'll explain better what is possible and what is not.

Comment: ok. let me post it to single spa repository. Thanks @ALex